# Editing single item in useFieldArray

Tags: react-hook-form

I'm using and loving `react-hook-form`. I've run across an issue where I have a list of items (let's say in the left column), then when you click on any item it will display an edit component for the selected item in the right column. The issue is when I switch between items, ***nested array values*** don't seem to update the data correctly.

I think I understand that because a new edit component isn't created for each parent item (I'm just passing the selected index down) the nested `useFieldArray` in the edit component still references the first parent item. If that's the case, I'm not exactly sure how to make sure a new `useFieldArray` is created for each item that gets selected.

Here's a codesandbox replicating the issue:

https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-brattain-r74lx

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just map over the `childItems` prop of your watched `item` inside your `<Details />` component instead of using `fields`. As you are using `watch` the `<Details />` will be re-rendered after appending a new child item.

[image: Edit gracious-hooks-534g3]

If your `<Details />` component should get more complex i would also suggest to use `useWatch` here instead of passing `watch`. Check this quote from the documentation for `useWatch`:

> Behaves similarly to the watch API, however, this will isolate
> re-rendering at the component level and potentially result in better
> performance for your application.

Here is an example using `useWatch`:

[image: Edit dazzling-khorana-k1ddm]

Comment: I tried so many different variations of watching and/or passing props, but didn't think to just watch the parent and grab the children :smh: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!